# how to change font size of multline formula in latex

Tags: math-mode, equations

I have a big formula, and I typed it in several lines in Latex using "multline" structure as follows:

```
\begin{multline}



\end{multline}
```

The problem is that, I want to reduce the font size of the formula. I searched a lot but most of the available answers works for "equation" not "multline". The reason I migrated from "equation" to "multline" is to type my formula in multiple lines.

Comment: all the methods for equation would apply to multine, specifically using `\small` before the environment and `\normalsize` after it (and perhaps some fixup of the vertical space)

Comment: It is `multline` not `multiline`.

Comment: @David: Is there a way to change the font size of a specific line other than using boxes.

Comment: You are right. I changed it to "multline". It was a typo thing.

Answer (score 1):

You have the `\medmath` command and the `medsize` environment from `nccmath`, which reduce the size of the formulae to about 80 % of `\displaystyle`. The package also defines a number of more specialised commands: `\medop`, `\medint`, `\mfrac`, `\mbinom`, and the `mmatrix` environment.

For instance, `\mfrac` typesets fractions at a size between `\tfrac` and `\dfrac`.